# Loop that adds numbers for a total value

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I am having trouble with my homework assignment. I have everything on the program pretty much functioning but the for loop to add the value of upgrades.

The assignment is as follows :

> After choosing a car off the user some engine upgrades. These upgrades can be from 0 (no upgrades) to 5 maximum upgrade. You need a nice loop for this too.
>
> Upgrades are $100 per level plus the cost of lower upgrades
>
> Example: Level 1 upgrade is $100
> Example: Level 2 upgrade is $100 + $200 = $300
> Example: Level 3 upgrade is $100 + $200 + $300 = $600
> etc etc etc etc etc etc etc etc etc etc etc etc etc...

This is the code that I have so far :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main () {
 int quoteNum = 0;
 int carChoice = 0;
 double carCost = 0;
 double upgradeCost = 0;
 int upgradeChoice = 0;
 int engineLevel = 0;
 double totalCost = 0;
 std::cout << std::fixed << std::showpoint << std::setprecision(2);
do {
    std::cout << "Welcome to Bob's used car lot and chop shop!\n";
    std::cout << "As you can see we have quite a few to choose from!\n";
    std::cout << "Which one would you like?: \n";
    std::cout << "[1] 2005 Volkswagen Beetle ($8,000)\n";
    std::cout << "[2] 2008 Pontiac G6 ($8,581)\n";
    std::cout << "[3] 2004 Chevy S-10 ($10,500)\n";
    std::cout << "[4] 2016 Jeep Patriot ($15,209)\n";
    std::cout << "[5] 2012 Jeep Wrangler Sport ($24,390)\n";
    std::cin >> carChoice;
} while (carChoice <= 0 || carChoice > 5);
switch (carChoice) {
    case 1:
        carCost = 8000.00;
        break;
    case 2:
        carCost = 8581.00;
        break;
    case 3:
        carCost = 10500.00;
        break;
    case 4:
        carCost = 15209.00;
        break;
    case 5:
        carCost = 24390.00;
        break;
}
  do {
      std::cout << "Quote:{" << quoteNum++ << "} ";
      std::cout << " Car($" << carCost << ")";
      std::cout << " E(" << engineLevel << ")";
      std::cout << " Upgrades($" << upgradeCost << ")" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Do you want to upgrade your car?\n";
      std::cout << "[-/+1] Downgrade / Upgrade Engine\n";
      std::cout << "[   2] Clear all upgrades\n";
      std::cout << "[   3] Reset car\n";
      std::cout << "[   4] Buy Car!!!\n";
      std::cout << "What would you like to do?: \n";
      std::cin >> upgradeChoice;
      if (upgradeChoice == -1) {
          engineLevel--;
          upgradeCost--;
      }
      if (upgradeChoice == 1) {
          for (upgradeCost = 0; upgradeCost <= 5; upgradeCost++) {
              upgradeCost = 100.00;
          }
      }
      if (upgradeChoice == 2) {
          engineLevel = 0;
          upgradeCost = 0.00;
      }
      if (upgradeChoice == 3) {
          std::cout << "Welcome to Bob's used car lot and chop shop!\n";
          std::cout << "As you can see we have quite a few to choose "
                  "from!\n";
          std::cout << "Which one would you like?: \n";
          std::cout << "[1] 2005 Volkswagen Beetle ($8,000)\n";
          std::cout << "[2] 2008 Pontiac G6 ($8,581)\n";
          std::cout << "[3] 2004 Chevy S-10 ($10,500)\n";
          std::cout << "[4] 2016 Jeep Patriot ($15,209)\n";
          std::cout << "[5] 2012 Jeep Wrangler Sport ($24,390)\n";
          std::cin >> carChoice;
          std::cin.ignore();
          switch (carChoice) {
              case 1:
                  carCost = 8000.00;
                  break;
              case 2:
                  carCost = 8581.00;
                  break;
              case 3:
                  carCost = 10500.00;
                  break;
              case 4:
                  carCost = 15209.00;
                  break;
              case 5:
                  carCost = 24390.00;
                  break;
          }
      }
      if (upgradeChoice == 4) {
          totalCost = carCost + upgradeCost;
          std::cout << "Bill: Car($" << carCost << ")";
          std::cout << " Upgrades($" << upgradeCost << ")";
          std::cout << " Total ($" << totalCost << ")\n";
          std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue";
          std::cin.ignore();
          std::cin.get();
          return 0;
      }
  } while (upgradeChoice >= -1 || upgradeChoice <= 4 && upgradeChoice != 0);
 }
```

Do you guys have any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: This is way too broad. What specifically are you having problems with? What about the loop do you need help with?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I need help with the UpgradeChoice and englineLevel loops. I need the program to add increments of 100 when the user inputs a 1 up to 5 times and remove the change when the user inputs -1.

Comment: Ok. And what have you tried to accomplish that? What went wrong? That's still too broad.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have tried numerous loops that don't work. They simply won't add 100 each time I press 1. They just stay at a fixed value.

Comment: @Hansel *Do you guys have any suggestions on what to do?* -- Yes, debug your own code.  Programming isn't about writing a program, seeing that it doesn't work, post on SO that it doesn't work, and then sit back and wait for an answer.  Debugging your own code is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have tried numerous loops that don't work. They simply won't add 100 each time I press 1. They just stay at a fixed value.

Comment: `upgradeCost = 100.00;` - there is no incrementing here - you are always just assigning `upgradeCost` the same value. Also you are using the same variable for the loop **and** the assignment, which by default breaks your code

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know what programming is. I am not as experienced with C++ as I'd like to be. It is an online class, so I receive little to no help on assignments from the professor, therefore I have to look for alternatives when it comes to help. I didnt ask you to write me the code. I asked what do you guys think I should do. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Hansel -- So the next time you have a bug in your code, you'll come back again?  This is the time to learn how to debug your code, as not doing so is being an irresponsible programmer.  No one writes perfect programs the first time, and debugging your own code is again, one of the things you **must** learn to do once you stick your toe into the the world of programming.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is what Stack Overflow is here for buddy. If you have no suggestions on what to do to help me. Then simply carry on.

Comment: @Hansel **NO** SO is **not** a debugging service. The Help page about [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is very specific about what questions are suited for SO and what not

Comment: @Hansel ---  *I have tried numerous loops that don't work* -- This is not the way to debug programs.  You should *step through your code* , and see what the values of variables are at specific times, print out values, see the flow of the program, etc.  You don't throw code on the wall until something sticks.  That is the advice to give you, and exactly what you're asking us to do, i.e. the job you should have been doing, regardless of your experience.

Comment: @UnholySheep I see. Awesome, ill try that. Thank you!

Comment: @UnholySheep I am not using it as a debugging service. I clearly said I needed help with my homework assignment. Which is completely fine according to the help page.

Comment: @Hansel -- To properly and thoroughly answer your question, we would have to 1) copy your code, 2) Paste it into a compiler 3) **Debug the code with a debugger** , 4) Write up an answer.  Did you see step 3)?  So you are asking us to debug your code.

Comment: @Hansel [You mean this](http://ideone.com/XfsUtB).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you! That helps a lot. I will try working around that to create it the code.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this task using classes, I recommend you start learning object oriented programming, because it's a really important part of programming, even though you did not start studying it at school. It makes your development way easier to see through.

For this project I used C++11 with GNU C/C++ Compiler.

Although it may contain errors or conventional errors, sorry about that!

**Included headers:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <vector>
#include <sstream> // std::stringstream
```

**Helpers:**

```
using USHORT = unsigned short;

template <typename T>
std::string convert_string(const T value) { 
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << value;
    return stream.str();
}

// note: use std::to_string instead of convert_string, if your compiler supports it
```

**Car class for representing a car of the dealership:**

```
class Car {
    USHORT year, engine_level;
    std::string name;
    float price, upgrade_cost;

public:
    Car(USHORT year, std::string name, float price) {
        this->year = year;
        this->name = name;
        this->price = price;

        engine_level = 1;
        upgrade_cost = 0.0;
    }

    std::string to_string() { return convert_string(year) + " " + name + " " + " ($" + convert_string(price) + ")"; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Car car) { 
        os << car.to_string() << std::endl;  
        return os;
    }

    std::string get_engine_level() { return "E(" + convert_string(engine_level) + ")"; }
    std::string get_price() { return "Car($" + convert_string(price) + ")"; }
    std::string get_upgrade_cost() { return "Upgrades($" + convert_string(upgrade_cost) + ")"; }

    void downgrade() {
        if(engine_level > 1) {
            engine_level--;
            upgrade_cost -= (100 + (engine_level * 100));
        } else {
            std::cout << "You can't downgrade your car from level 1!" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void upgrade() { 
        engine_level++;
        upgrade_cost += (100 + (engine_level * 100)); 
    }

    void clear_upgrades() { engine_level = 1; upgrade_cost = 0.0; }

    std::string get_total_cost() { return "Total ($" + convert_string(price + upgrade_cost) + ")"; }
};
```

**Class for representing the dealership and workshop:**

```
class CarDealerAndWorkshop {
    std::vector<Car> cars_for_sale;

public:
    CarDealerAndWorkshop(std::vector<Car> cars_for_sale) { this->cars_for_sale = cars_for_sale; }

    void welcome_message() {
        std::cout <<
            "Welcome to Bob's used car lot and chop shop!\n"
            "As you can see we have quite a few to choose from!\n"
            "Which one would you like?: ";
    }

    void upgrade_message() {
        std::cout << 
            "Do you want to upgrade your car?\n"
            "[-/+1] Downgrade / Upgrade Engine\n"
            "[   2] Clear all upgrades\n"
            "[   3] Reset car\n"
            "[   4] Buy Car!!!\n"
            "What would you like to do?: ";
    }

    void show_cars() {
        int counter = 1;
        for (auto car : cars_for_sale) {
            std::cout << "[" << counter++ << "] ";
            std::cout << car;
        }
    }

    unsigned number_of_cars() { return cars_for_sale.size(); }

    bool validate(const USHORT number) { return number <= number_of_cars() && number >= 0; }

    Car* get_car_by_num(const USHORT num) { return &cars_for_sale[num]; }

    void buy(const int number) { cars_for_sale.erase(cars_for_sale.begin() + number); }

    bool are_there_cars() { 
        if(number_of_cars() == 0) {
            std::cout << "We are very sorry, but we have ran out of cars!\n";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

**Class for representing customers:**

```
class Customer {
    Car* car_choice;
    std::string name;

public:
    Customer(std::string name) { this->name = name; }
    void set_car_choice(Car* car) { car_choice = car; }
    Car* get_car_choice() { return car_choice; }
};
```

**And finally the client code:**

```
int main () {
    CarDealerAndWorkshop Bobs_Dealership({
        {2005, "Volkswagen Beetle", 8000},
        {2008, "Pontiac G6", 8581},
        {2004, "Chevy S-10", 10500},
        {2016, "Jeep Patriot", 15209},
        {2012, "Jeep Wrangler Sport", 24390}
    });

    Customer customer("Bill");

    Bobs_Dealership.welcome_message();

    bool is_quit_dealer = false;

    while(!is_quit_dealer) {

        if(!Bobs_Dealership.are_there_cars())
            is_quit_dealer = true;

        USHORT car_choice;

        do {
            Bobs_Dealership.show_cars();
            std::cin >> car_choice;
        } while (!Bobs_Dealership.validate(car_choice-1));

        customer.set_car_choice(Bobs_Dealership.get_car_by_num(car_choice-1));

        unsigned quote_num = 0;
        bool is_quit_workshop = false;
        short upgrade_choice;

        while(!is_quit_workshop) {

            std::cout << "Quote:{" << quote_num++ << "} "              << std::endl;
            std::cout << customer.get_car_choice()->get_price()        << std::endl;
            std::cout << customer.get_car_choice()->get_engine_level() << std::endl;
            std::cout << customer.get_car_choice()->get_upgrade_cost() << std::endl;

            Bobs_Dealership.upgrade_message();
            std::cin >> upgrade_choice;

            switch(upgrade_choice) {
                case -1: customer.get_car_choice()->downgrade();      break;
                case  1: customer.get_car_choice()->upgrade();        break;
                case  2: customer.get_car_choice()->clear_upgrades(); break;
                case  3: is_quit_workshop = true; break;
                case  4: 
                    std::cout << customer.get_car_choice()->get_price() << std::endl;
                    std::cout << customer.get_car_choice()->get_upgrade_cost() << std::endl;
                    std::cout << customer.get_car_choice()->get_total_cost() << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue" << std::endl;
                    std::cin.sync();
                    std::cin.get();
                    Bobs_Dealership.buy(car_choice-1);
                    is_quit_workshop = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good start. I'd like to give you some hints, if I may. As you mentioned C++11, you could use [`using`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) instead of `typedef`, [range-based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) and [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) instead of your `convert_string`. Start using [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) and prefer `'\n'` to `std::endl` unless you really need to flush the output.

Comment: @Bob__ Thanks Bob for the good advices! Yes I wanted to use `std::to_string` but my MinGW doesn't support it somehow, I need to update it shortly.